# Add feature of network manager not working

Tags: network-manager

Network manager in 16.04 will not allow openvpn to be added in the settings screen.
The 'add' button does not become 'solid' it stays in a faded state.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to follow to resolve issue;**

1- make sure openvpn is installed.

2- open terminal and type -- nm-connection-editor -- and press enter.

3- click the add button - making sure you’ve selected the correct network conection.

4- select openvpn from the drop down list.

Comment: thanks but this makes no difference to the fact that the 'add' button is grayed out and therefore no details for the vpn can be added, so no vpn.